# HttpContext is null when Send request from Telegrom bot

Tags: c#, telegram

I am working with `Telegram` to make a bot , I want to add `session` when User Send a request (actually when choose a option in bot) . 
when I try to add `session` , `HttpContext` is null and it throw an exception . 
I tried to to tht like below :

```
 private void Bot_OnUpdate(object sender, UpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Update.Type == UpdateType.CallbackQueryUpdate)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("SADS", "SDFS");


            _dbService.LoginRoom(e.Update.CallbackQuery.From.Id, Int32.Parse(e.Update.CallbackQuery.Data.ToString()));

//other codes
            }}
```

but when I try to access HttpContext in constructor it exist but Session is null and I couldn't add Any item to it .

```
public class TelegramClass
    {
        HttpContext CC;
   public TelegramClass()
        {
            CC = HttpContext.Current;

        }}
```

I have search online but I couldn't find any similar question .

Comment: Do you use pooling method to get your messages  ?

Comment: No Don't use pooling

Comment: If you use hooking method, you probably set your callback on asp.net web api, right ?